# How does the scanf function work in C?

Tags: c, scanf

Why do you require ampersand (&) in the `scanf` function. What will the output or type of error (compile or runtime) be in the following C code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int a;
    printf("enter integer:");
    scanf("%d", a);
}
```

Comment: As an aside, `main` returns `int`, not `void`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `&` in C is an operator that returns the address of the operand. Think of it this way, if you would simply give `scanf` the variable `a` without the `&`, it will be passed to it by-value, which means `scanf` will not be able to set its value for you to see. Passing it by-reference (using `&` actually passes a pointer to `a`) allows `scanf` to set it so that the calling functions will see the change too.

Regarding the specific error, you can't really tell. The behavior is undefined. Sometimes, it might silently continue to run, without you knowing `scanf` changed some value somewhere in your program. Sometimes it will cause the program to crash immediately, like in this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("enter integer: ");
    scanf("%d",a);
    printf("entered integer: %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it shows this:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

And executing shows a segmentation fault:

```
$ ./test 
enter integer: 2
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 3):

In C, all function arguments are passed by value; any changes to the function's formal parameter are not reflected in the actual parameter.  For example:

```
void foo(int bar)
{
  bar = bar + 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  int x = 0;
  printf("x before foo = %d\n", x);
  foo(x);
  printf("x after foo = %d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the program will be

```
x before foo = 0
x after foo = 0
```

because `bar` receives the value of `x` (0), not a reference to `x` itself.  Changing `bar` has no effect on `x`.

In C, the way around this is to pass a *pointer* to a variable:

```
void foo(int *bar)
{
  *bar = *bar + 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  int x = 0;
  printf("x before foo = %d\n", x);
  foo(&x);
  printf("x after foo = %d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Now the output of the program is

```
x before foo = 0
x after foo = 1
```

This time, the formal parameter `bar` is not an int, but a *pointer* to int, and it receives the *address* of `x` (given by the expression `&x` in the call to `foo`), not the value contained in x.  The expression `*bar` means "get the value in the location bar *points to*", so `*bar = *bar + 1` corresponds to `x = x + 1`.

Since `scanf()` needs to write to its arguments, it expects those arguments to typed as pointers.  The "%d" conversion specifier expects the corresponding argument to be a pointer to int (`int *`), the "%u" conversion specifier expects a pointer to unsigned int (`unsigned *`), "%s" expects a pointer to char (`char *`), "%f" expects a pointer to float (`float *`), etc.  In your example, since `a` is typed `int`, you need to use the expression `&a` to get a pointer.

Note that if `a` were already a pointer type, you would not need to use the `&` operator in the call to `scanf()`:

```
int main(void)
{
  int a, *pa;      // declare pa as a pointer to int
  ...
  pa = &a;         // assign address of a to pa
  scanf("%d", pa); // scanf() will write to a through pa
  ...
}
```

Note also that when passing an array to a function (such as when using the "%s" conversion specifier to read a string), you don't need to use the `&` operator; the array expression will implicitly be converted to a pointer type:

```
int main(void)
{
  char name[20];
  ...
  scanf("%19s", name); // name implicitly converted from "char [20]" to "char *"
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking a question like this, I would recommend just learning for now "it just does".

You will learn that you need an ampersand because `scanf` takes one or more pointer arguments.  If a is an int variable, it is not a pointer.  &a ("the address of a") is a pointer, so it will work with `scanf`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in C, functions parameters are **passed by value**. In order for the `scanf()` function to modify the '`a`' variable in your main() function, the **address** of '`a`' shall be given to `scanf()`, hence the usage of the ampersand (address of).

Answer (score 1):

Because `scanf` requires a pointer to the variable (i.e. a reference) that the value will go into.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *always* need to use an `&` with `scanf`.  What you need to do is to pass *pointers*.  If you're new to C, you should spend some time reading the comp.lang.c FAQ:

http://c-faq.com/

Specifically:

- [Why doesn't the call scanf("%d", i) work?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1.html)
- [Why does the call scanf("%s", s) work?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1a.html)

Answer (score 0):

The '&' in `scanf` is only required to get the address of a variable.  You *can* use `scanf` without '&' by using pointers:

```
int myInt;
int * pointer_to_int;
pointer_to_int = &myInt;
scanf("%d", pointer_to_int);
```

In general, using '&' is often easier than creating pointer to avoid using the '&'.