# Undesired Output - Printing out Two Numbers

Tags: c, io, stdin

I'm fairly new to C programming, so I figured I'd try writing a simple program to
print two `int` numbers. I prompt the user for both numbers, and then just print both using `printf`

However, upon running the program, I get a result which is really bizarre.

For instance...

```
Enter first int: 5
Enter second int: 3
First int: 2130567168
Second int: 2686756
```

My code is below...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x, y;

    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%i", x);

    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%i", y);

    printf("%i\n%i%\n",x,y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `scanf("%i", x);` to `scanf("%i", &x);`. Do same for second scan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c scanf question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062648/c-scanf-question)

Answer (score 5):

This is because you forgot the `&` in the [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) statement. So change it to this:

```
scanf("%i", &y);
scanf("%i", &x);
          //^ See here
```

Also you have one `%` too much in your printf statement. Because `%` is for [format specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), so if you want to print the symbol `%` you have to write it 2 times:

```
printf("%i\n%i%\n",x,y);
            //^ Is a format specifier so if you want to print the symbol, write it 2 times
```

**Side note:**

If you use the specifier `%i` in your scanf statement and you enter something like this: `035` the output would become `29`, because it would be interpreted as octal number. So if you don't want that you can change the specifier to `%d` and `035` becomes `35`

Comment: What would adding the `&` do?

Comment: @Delfini So that you actually scan it into the address of the variable

Comment: Ah, I see. So having `x` there just means that it's adding whatever number I input to the data already at `x`?

Comment: @Delfini So that you are able to store the number of your input you have to give the address of your variable to scanf

Answer (score 2):

Change the code like this.

```
scanf("%i", &y);
scanf("%i", &x);
```

While storing the value to the variable you have to give the address of that variable. If you are using the arrays you don't need to give that. In printf statement , use the needed specifiers.

```
printf("%i\n%i\n",x,y);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the '&' in the scanf statement:

```
scanf("%i", &y);
scanf("%i", &x);
      //^ this
```