# What happen if '&' operator is not included in scanf while taking input?

Tags: c

hii everyone i want to ask a question that what happen if '&' operator is not included in scanf.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main() 
 {
     int x;
     scanf("%d", x); 
   /* than what type of value will scanf store in x if there is                  
       not address of operator. */
     printf("%d", x);
     return 0;
  }
```

either program crash or some garbage value prints out. I m little bit confused.

Comment: The program has undefined behaviour, that's what happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How does the scans function work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062648/how-does-the-scanf-function-work-in-c)

Comment: r u sure its undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's **Undefined Behaviour**. Program can print 0, 42, or the lyrics to the national anthem.

Comment: Yes it's undefined behavior. You should get a warning from your compiler about this.

Comment: `scanf()` expects an address, so it will treat `x` value (which isn't even initialized in your case) as an address. This address may be valid or invalid, therefore unexpected behavior.

Comment: I don't get any warning

Comment: The question tells us that you *know* it should be `&x`. Your program has not initialised `x` so passing `x` is undefined behaviour. Even with `x` initialised, it is wrong.

Comment: Then turn up your warnings to pedantic levels. Or use a compiler developer in the last decade; preferably *both*. Unless the expressions provided as arguments match the requirements of the [format specifier(s)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) in the format string, it's *undefined behavior*.

Comment: MSVC gives 2 warnings. 1) 'scanf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int', and 2) uninitialized local variable 'x' used.

Comment: i m using mingw compiler. And it doesn't matter whether x is initialized or not but important is behavior of scanf  in absence of &.

Comment: It is **not** important how it behaves without `&`. It is wrong, and exploring that might give you an understanding  but otherwise is a [wild goose chase](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wild-goose+chase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scanf will try to write the value it read to the address stored **in** x. When you use the & operator, it will write the value to the address **of** x.

In this case x is a variable on the stack. Variables on the stack are (in C) not automatically initialized, so initially x will probably contain a garbage value. scanf will thus try to write the input value to a garbage address in memory.

This may either cause corruption of the program code or data (which may crash the program or result in unexpected behavior), or cause a segmentation fault (which will cause the OS to abort the program) if the value in x points to memory to which the program is not allowed to write (invalid or read-only memory). What exactly will happen depends on the value of x, which may be a value left over from another program, and this may be different each time you run the program.

Comment: so printf will print out garbage VALUE of x.

Comment: @AmanWarudkar that is correct. If the program does not crash on the scanf, printf will print out the (garbage) value of x. Note how this is different from scanf - printf only has inputs so it takes values for its arguments, scanf has outputs so it takes pointers as its arguments to which it can write the result.

Comment: hey one more question as you above say if scanf has address operator than it will write at ADDRESS of x AND in absence of '&' operator it will write the Value to the ADDRESS stored in x which contain garbage address whether it is valid or not,  is I am RIGHT

Comment: If the address in `x` is garbage, the system might object. Or it might do it (if the address is allowable) but then create bugs because you are throwing tomatoes at the window.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `scanf` with the `%d` conversion specifier, the corresponding argument needs to be an expression that evaluates to the *location* of an integer object into which `scanf` will write the input value:

```
scanf( "%d", location-expression );
```

*`location-expression`* can take on multiple forms.  To read into a single scalar object like `x`, you could use the expression `&x`.

```
scanf( "%d", &x ); // &x evaluates to the location of x
```

Or, you could use a pointer variable that's initialized to point to `x`:

```
int *p = &x;      // p stores the address of x
scanf( "%d", p ); // scanf writes to x *through* p; p == &x
```

The *expression* `p` is equivalent to the expression `&x` in this case.  We don't use the `&` operator on `p`, because we want write to the address *stored* in `p`, not the address *of* `p`.

When you write

```
scanf( "%d", x );
```

you're telling `scanf` to store input to the address *stored in `x`*.  There are several problems with that:

1. `x` is not explicitly initialized to anything; its value is *indeterminate*;
2. Because of 1, the odds that `x` contains a value that corresponds to a *valid* pointer value (that is, the location of an object in your program) are extremely low;
3. The type of the expression `x` is `int`, but `%d` expects its corresponding argument to have type `int *` - any modern compiler should yell at you.

Comment: Thankyou for such a nice explanation but canu explain "point no 2".

Comment: @AmanWarudkar: Basically, the value stored in `x` is not a valid pointer value.